# Simple histogram doubling values on one edge

Tags: matplotlib

Anyone knows why this simple Matplotlib histogram doubles the size of the last column in relation to the others?

```
bin_edges = np.arange(1, 13, 1)
plt.hist(data = df_sample, x = 'birth_-_month', bins = bin_edges);
```

The data seem to be fine:

[image: Values to plot]

But the histogram has this aspect:

[image: Histogram plotted]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a histogram if you are plotting each data point? Use a bar chart instead

Comment: Your data is discrete and contains the integers from 1 to 12. The histogram distributes the data into bins of size 1, starting at 1. All bins are half open intervals, [1,2), [2,3), etc. however the last bin is the closed interval [11,12]. This means it contains the values 11 ***and*** 12, and hence roughly doubly the values than all others. You can let the bins range up to 13 to solve this. Or let the bins range from [-0.5, 0.5), [0.5, 1.5) etc. Or you come to the conclusion that a histogram for discrete values is not so great and use a bar plot of the value_counts instead.